# SQL Access — Limit subquery only

Tags: sql, ms-access, limit

I'm trying to obtain a list of actors a particular director has worked with, and a list of films that these actors have been in from a movie database.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A_First_Name, A_Last_Name, Film_Title
FROM 

  (SELECT * 
  FROM Actor, Film, Film_Actor_Director_Genre
  WHERE Actor.AID=Film_Actor_Director_Genre.AID
  AND Film.FID=Film_Actor_Director_Genre.FID)

WHERE A_First_Name IN 

  (SELECT A_First_Name
  FROM 

    (SELECT * 
    FROM Actor, Director, 
    Film_Actor_Director_Genre
    WHERE 
    Actor.AID=Film_Actor_Director_Genre.AID
    AND 
    Director.DID=Film_Actor_Director_Genre.DID)

  WHERE D_First_Name=[Director’s first name?]
  OR D_Last_Name=[Director’s last name?]);
```

Assuming I want to know the list of actors that director D01 has worked with, the sample result is like so:

```
Actor    Film
-----    ----
A01      F01
A01      F02
A01      F03
A01      F04
A02      F01
A02      F02
A02      F05
A02      F06
A03      F01
A04      F01
A04      F02
A04      F09
A05      F01
A05      F02
A06      F10
A07      F01
A07      F02
A07      F04
etc.     etc.
```

However as the list of actors D01 has worked with could be extremely long, I would like to show only the top 5 actors (i.e. actors that worked in most no. films with D01), and all the films the actors have been in. So I want to only limit actors but not films. The desired result would be:

```
Actor    Film
-----    ----
A01      F01
A01      F02
A01      F03
A01      F04
A02      F01
A02      F02
A02      F05
A02      F06
A04      F01
A04      F02
A04      F09
A05      F01
A05      F02
A07      F01
A07      F02
A07      F04
```

I tried to implement the `SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5` syntax in various subqueries but they returned strange combinations of 5 results, e.g.

```
Actor    Film
-----    ----
A01      F01
A01      F02
A02      F01
A02      F02
A06      F10
```

How can I limit the results to show only the top 5 actors that have worked with D01 and the all the films these actors have acted in? Thanks for your time, would appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: This is a fairly simple query, but I am a bit confused with what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to list actors that have been in the most movies with a single director? but you don't want to display the director - only the actor and movies they have been in?

Comment: Yes you are right. I will edit my question to make that clear.

Comment: Give me a second to write up the query :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this will work

```
select
  *
from
  actors a

  inner join film_actor_director_genre fadg on 
    on fadg.aid = a.aid

  inner join film f on
    f.fid = fadg.fid

  -- This should return all actors that have been in 
  -- at lead 5 movies with a director. Note the count
  -- ordering and limit
  inner join (
    select top 5
      a.aid
    from
      film_actor_director_genre
    group by
      a.aid,
      d.did
    having
      count(*) >= 5
    order by
      count(*)
  ) t1 on
    t1.aid = a.aid
```

Little tricky with out being able to test the query. Should work!

Comment: I don't think Access recognises the `LIMIT` syntax...also I can't seem to get this to work, tried editing the `JOIN` syntax to no avail

Comment: It seems access doesn't like limit you are correct. It seems to prefer top from my google search. Check the edited version .. not sure if it will work, but it might.

Comment: Thanks! Just want to add that the join function in Access requires parentheses so I had to add that in: `(((Actor A 
INNER JOIN Film_Actor_Director_Genre FADG on FADG.AID = A.AID) 
INNER JOIN Film F on F.FID = FADG.FID) 
INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 5 AID, COUNT(*) AS [# from FADG] 
GROUP BY AID, DID 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) t1 ON t1.AID = A.AID))` but otherwise it works. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This is access?

Assuming his query is correct, you can replace the limit (and having) with something a little more simple:

```
 select top 5 aid, count(*) as qty from film_actor_director_genre group by aid, did order by 2 desc
```

If access can't handle that order by clause you can switch it back to

```
 select top 5 aid, count(*) as qty from film_actor_director_genre group by aid, did order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with the order clause, used it and it indeed worked.